# Running subversion under apache and mod_python

Tags: python, svn, apache

My Apache server runs on some non-default (not-root) account. When it tries to run a python script which in turn executes a subversion check-out command, 'svn checkout' fails with the following error message:

```
svn: Can't open file '/root/.subversion/servers': Permission denied
```

At the same time running that python script with subversion checkout command inside from command line under the same user account goes on perfectly well.

Apache server 2.2.6 with mod_python 3.2.8 runs on Fedora Core 6 machine.

Can anybody help me out? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the environment you apache process is running under is a little unusual.  For whatever reason, svn seems to think the user configuration files it needs are in /root.  You can avoid having svn use the root versions of the files by specifying on the command line which config directory to use, like so:

```
svn --config-dir /home/myuser/.subversion checkout http://example.com/path
```

While not fixing your enviornment, it will at least allow you to have your script run properly...

Comment: Much appreciated, Douglas, this quickly solved the same problem I was having.

Comment: You can specify site-wide configuration using `svn --config-dir /etc/subversion`

Answer (score 0):

Try granting the Apache user (the user that the apache service is running under) r+w permissions on that file.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Apache's error log give you a clue?

Maybe it has to do with SELinux. Check /var/log/audit/audit.log and adjust your SELinux configuration accordingly, if the audit.log file indicates that it's SELinux which denies Apache access.

Answer (score 0):

The Permission Denied error is showing that the script is running with root credentials, because it's looking in root's home dir for files.

I suggest you change the hook script to something that does:

```
id > /tmp/id
```

so that you can check the results of that to make sure what the uid/gid and euid/egid are.  You will probably find it's not actually running as the user you think it is.

My first guess, like Troels, was also SELinux, but that would only be my guess if you are absolutely sure the script through Apache is running with exactly the same user/group as your manual test.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to all who answered the question. Anyway, I think I solved the mistery.

SELinux is completely disabled on the machine, so the problem is definitely in 'svn co' not being able to found config_dir for the user account it runs under.

Apache / mod_python doesn't read in shell environment of the user account which apache is running  on. Thus for examle no $HOME is seen by mod_python when apache 
is running under some  real user ( not nobody )

Now 'svn co' has a flag --config-dir which points to configuration directory to read params from. By default it is $HOME/.subversion, i.e. it corresponds to the user account home directory. Apparently when no $HOME exists mod_python goes to root home dir ( /root) and tries to fiddle with .subversion content over there - which is obviously
fails miserably.

putting

SetEnv HOME /home/qa

into the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf doesn't solve the problem because of SetEnv having nothing to do with shell environment - it only sets apache related environment

Likewise PythonOption - sets only mod_python related variables which can be read with req.get_options()  after that

Running 'svn co --config-dir /home/ ...' definitely gives a workaround for running from within mod_python, but gets in the way of those who will try to run the script from command line.

So the proposed ( and working) solution is to set HOME environment variable prior to starting appache.

For example in /etc/init.d/httpd  script

```
    QAHOME=/home/qa
    ...
    HOME=$QAHOME LANG=$HTTPD_LANG daemon $httpd $OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is apache is being started with the environment variables of root, so it thinks that it should find its config files in /root/. This is NOT the case.
what happens is if you do sudo apache2ctl start, it pulls your $HOME variable from the sudo $HOME=/root/

I have just found a solution to this problem myself (although with mod_perl, but same thing)

run this command (if its apache 1, remove the 2):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

When /etc/init.d/apache2 starts apache, it sets all the proper environment variables that apache should be running under.