# Invoking Wine From Apache

Tags: python, apache, mod-python, wine

I have Apache/2.2.11 using mod_python 3.3.1/Python 2.5 running under Gentoo linux.  In my python script I invoke a win32 exe using wine (os.popen2 call).  This works fine outside of Apache but under mod_python I get:

```
wine: cannot open /root/.wine : Permission denied
```

in /var/log/apache/error_log.  My apache install is not running as the root user/group.  Any ideas why it's looking into /root/.wine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because `$HOME` isn't set correctly...

Btw. Are you really sure invoking wine from mod_python is a good idea?

If you are sure, something like that could work...

```
from subprocess import Popen        

HOME = '/the/home/of/www-data' #PLEASE edit
proc = Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdin=PIPE,
             stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True,
             cwd=HOME, env={"HOME":HOME)
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes.  Your answer lead me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133860/running-subversion-under-apache-and-modpython.  I hacked the /etc/init.d/apache file to set $HOME properly.

Comment: Oh, and using wine from mod_python is a horrible, horrible idea.  Too much legacy code.  It's on the schedule to be re-written, but I'm sure know how schedules slip and slide.

Comment: :-) I would rather not hack /etc/init.d/apache since after a distro upgrade it could be reset... I think it's better to set it when using Popen. So another process spawned can not override it...

Answer (score 1):

I was also having very hard time and did lots of researched but failed. Finally found the simplest way by adding `'WINEPREFIX="/srv/www/.wine"'` in `/etc/init.d/httpd` file as:

```
case $ARGV in
start|stop|restart|graceful|graceful-stop)
    WINEPREFIX="/srv/www/.wine" $HTTPD -k $ARGV
    ERROR=$?
    ;;
```

Copy `/root/.wine to /srv/www/.wine` and change the owner to apache (from root). Hope this will solve the problem.